# Возможно ли разбить callbacks по файлам? Python, aiogram

Tags: python, callback, handlers

Есть файлы:

```
bot.py
/handlers
____/admin
________/panel.py
________/users.py
____/client
________account.py
```

Мне нужно каким-то образом разбить все хендлеры по этим файлам, то-есть, чтобы каждый хендлер реагировал только на "локальные" события, из своего файла. Не могу понять как это реализовать, уже несколько часов сижу.

Сейчас у меня в каждом файле хендлеры регистрируются, типа такого:

```
# from handlers/client/account.py
def register_handlers_client_account(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(client_account_messages)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(client_account_callbacks)
```

```
# from handlers/admin/panel.py
def register_handlers_admin_panel(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(admin_panel_messages)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(admin_panel_callbacks)
```

И в основном файле бота:

```
# from bot.py
account.register_handlers_client_account(dp)
panel.register_handlers_admin_panel(dp)
users.register_handlers_admin_users(dp)
```

Но работают они только в файле `account.py`, пытался переставлять местами всё что только можно - что-то начинает работать - другое перестаёт.

Можете подсказать, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать конструкцию

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

`__name__` - это переменная, которая содержит имя модуля, из которого запускается. Если ты запускаешь код файла в самом файле, то `__name__` будет равно `'__main__'`.
А если ты, к примеру, импортировал файл в `test.py` и оттуда запустил, то `__main__` импортированного файла будет `'test'`

Comment: На сколько я знаю при таком раскладе нельзя будет импортировать файлы. А у меня они импортируются в основной файл "bot.py".

Comment: Почему? Такие файлы можно импортировать, просто код, который в конструкции if name = main, будет выполняться только из основного файла

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, точнее мою ошибку.

Дело в том, что callback_handler указанный в первом файле, "перебивает" собой все остальные хандлеры. Чтобы подобного не происходило, в каждом файле нужно указывать, на какие именно каллбэки должны реагировать хандлеры.

Например, я создал админ панель, и в хандлере я должен указать список принимаемых из админ панели каллбэков (то же самое и с message_handler):
[image: Список принимаемых каллбэков]

Потом эти хандлеры регистрируем в основном файле:
[image: Регистрация хандлеров]